# How can I return to the start of the class in Java?

Tags: java

Here's what I'm working on: I have been working on a program in Java for a while now and I still have come to the ultimatum that I cannot do one thing, return to the start of the code - I always end up with a syntax error here or there.

I'm no pro so don't hate on me if this is an easy question!

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Name {
    public static void main(String args[])  {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int Name;
        int Confirmation = 5; 


    System.out.print("What Game Would You Like To Buy? Type '9' for Help. Type '0' To View The Selection Of Games Available: ");
    System.out.println("");
    Name = keyboard.nextInt();

    if (Name == 0) {
        System.out.println("Fantasy World (0.99). Type '1' to Purchase.");
        System.out.println("Sir Wags A Lot (0.99). Type '2' to Purchase.");
        System.out.println("Take a Path (1.99). Type '3' to Purchase.");
        // (plus a few more calls to println)
            } 
    if (Name == 9) {
        System.out.println("Help:"
                + "All games are corresponded to a single integer ranging from 1 to 8. Type 0 in the main bar too see the range of games."
                + "Too see this help message, type 9."
                + "For more information on each game, type the number followed by that number again. For example, I would type 22 too see more information on Sir Wags A Lot.");
    }

    if (Name == 1) {
        System.out.println("Fantasy World is £0.99, are you sure you want to pay? Type '1' for Yes or '0' for No: ");
        Confirmation = keyboard.nextInt();
    }
        if (Confirmation == 1) {
            System.out.print("Thank You For Purchasing!");

        }
        if (Confirmation == 0) {
            System.out.print("Ok, Come Again!");
        }
    if (Name == 11) {
        System.out.println("Fantasy World:");
        System.out.println("Title: Fantasy World");
        System.out.println("Genre: RPG");
        System.out.println("Description: Where you can live your dreams");
        System.out.println("Price: £0.99");

        }
    if (Name == 22) {
        System.out.println("Sir Wags A Lot:");
        // (plus more println calls)
        }
    if (Name == 33) {
        System.out.println("Take a Path:");
         // (plus more println calls)
        }
    if (Name == 44) {
        System.out.println("River Clear Up:");
        // (plus more println calls)
        }
    if (Name == 55) {
        System.out.println("PinBall:");
        // (plus more println calls)
        }
    if (Name == 66) {
        System.out.println("Ghost Girl:");
        // (plus more println calls)
        }
    if (Name == 77) {
        System.out.println("Dress Up:");
        //(plus more println calls)
        }
    if (Name == 88) {
        System.out.println("Where Is My Hat?:");
        //(plus more println calls)
        }
    }

}
```

So basically, the variable is that the user types in a double digit integer to activate the bottom sub-classes. Say I want more info on 'Fantasy World':

I type `11` in the input console, it displays the text - maybe I want to buy the game but obviously, I don't want to restart the whole program - could I make it easier to just add some more code to the bottom of each sub-class that will return it to the integer input at the top again?

I've tried as easiest as possible to explain my situation.

Comment: It's better to post your code directly in the question.

Comment: I've got 10 minutes left of lesson - it was easier to do this instead of indenting everything...

Comment: Are you seriously asking us to explain the concept of a loop?!?

Comment: well sorry, I'm a 14 year old student who's currently sitting in a computer science class ripping my hair out. I asked for a block of code, not the dictionary entry.

Comment: When I was in school we asked questions to the teacher or a fellow student, not to stackoverflow :/ Unless we were in an exam of course.

Comment: Jamie, don't worry about the above.  I believe people forget how to be civil sometimes, and this goes doubly for engineers because we're trained in being pedantic.  Look at @saadq 's answer regarding wrapping your logic within a loop.  If you're used to another language that allows a `goto` statement to branch back to the top of a procedure/function/method, then you'll need to think more in terms of looping constructs such as explained here: [Java Loops Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_loop_control.htm).

Comment: @tgm1024 maybe I'm a bit rude and pedantic, but I don't think stackoverflow is the right place to ask extremely basic questions like that. Such questions (and their respective answers) offer no value to anyone who can actually write code.

Comment: @ammoQ, I'm sorry, but that's devoid of balanced arbitration.  What constitutes extremely basic?  I see **nothing** in the SO charter that says we should criticize a 14 year old like THAT.  There were 3 calm and non-ascerbic answers given.  Learn from their example.

Answer (score 1):

You basically just need to put your code inside a `do-while` loop. You can read about it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html). The program will keep running until the condition for the `while` statement is true.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a loop - a do-while, or while- that will run forever (`while(true)`). Add another input type to your conditions which will be the exit code. If your exit code is 99, then when the user types 99 you can `return;` and that will end your program.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the quickest fix:

- Rename your main function to programLoop
- Make a new main function that says this:

code:

```
public static void main(String args[])  {
  while(true) {
    programLoop(args);
  }
}
```

The proper fix is to read up on how loops works, so you understand how the program flows.

Comment: This is clear, but also might confuse him, but only in that the exit criteria would be more complicated to trickle upward to the calling loop.  One thing at a time for a newcomer to programming.